# How to create new column when join two tables using UNION?

Tags: oracle

I want to append two tables and create a new common column call "Account_Type". How to create in oracle?

```
Prepaid sales Table
Number     Date          sales_person
3452       23/11/2020      fgaa
4525       12/12/2020      gwfa
```

```
Postpaid sales Table
Number     Date          sales_person
5681       10/10/2020      fsdSAD
6723       02/09/2020      gwfage
```

I am expecting the final table

```
Number     Date          sales_person  Account_Type
3452       23/11/2020      fgaa        Prepaid  
4525       12/12/2020      gwfa        Prepaid
5681       10/10/2020      fsdSAD      Postpaid
6723       02/09/2020      gwfage      Postpaid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Pseudo column for account type  in both tables

```
select a.*,'Prepaid' account_type
from sales_prepaid a  
union
select b.*,'Postpaid' account_type
from sales_postpaid b
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
create table final as
    select number, date, sales_person, 'Prepaid' account_type
    from prepaid
    union
    select number, date, sales_person, 'Postpaid' account_type
    from postpaid
```